# How to do white-listed HTML encoding in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, markdown, xss

I'm working on a mini-CMS module for one of my projects, where users are allowed to edit content in markdown. I'm using `markdown-it` for parsing and showing a preview.

I was thinking a lot about how to send the input to the server, and also how to store it in the database. I came to a conclusion to avoid duplicating the markdown parsing at server-side, and send both markdown and the parsed HTML to the server. I think nowadays the added overhead is minimal, even on a site where edits are heavy.

So at final stage I still need to validate the HTML sent to the server, as it can be a security bottleneck of the system. I've read a lot about Microsoft's implementation of AntiXSS, and how it is (or was) quite unusable for such scenarios, as it was too gready. For example I've found [this article](https://eksith.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/antixss-4-2-breaks-everything/) with even a helper code (using HTMLAgilityPack) to give a usable sanitizing implementation.

Unfortunately I haven't found anything newer than 2013 on this topic. I'd like to ask at present how to do a proper HTML encoding where there are allowed tags and attributes, but still safe from any kind of XSS attacks? Is such a code like in the article still needed, or are there any built-in solutions?

Also, if my choice of client-side markdown parsing is not viable, what are some other options? What I want to avoid, is duplicating all kinds of markdown logic at both client and server. For example I've prepared several custom extensions for `markdown-it`, etc.

Comment: In MVC by default XSS attack is validated. So if any one tries to post javascript or HTML code he lands with the error.

Comment: @Div: That validation is essentially useless.  You must always escape all output.

Comment: @Div But isn't it stripping out all the HTML? On the other end, when I use `[ValidateInput(false)]` on the corresponding action which receives the input, then it will do nothing with it.

Comment: @SLaks Ideally I'd like to have the already validated HTML in my database, so I could just spit it out in JSON together with some other data.

Comment: Here's some code https://eksith.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/antixss-4-2-breaks-everything/ but note that it still blacklists (other than claimed). It starts with an arbitrary HTML document and then strips things away. This is not very safe. Generally, you want to parse the HTML using HtmlAgilityPack and then construct a *new* document with only what you consider safe. Then, make HtmlAgilityPack format that document as HTML.

Comment: @usr Yeah it's the same link what I included :) Thanks for your thoughts though. I don't quite get what you mean by it still blacklists. For me removing everything except the specified ones sounds equivalent to white-list. I'll check that code again, I might have missed something.

Comment: The code might miss certain things entirely due to bugs. White and blacklisting are of course equivalent from a functional standpoint. The difference is that blacklisting if prone to bugs due to forgetting something. Taking things out of an DOM is blacklisting.; I wondered where I got that link from actually. Turns out it was from here :)

Comment: But what about taking out everything except allowed? It still is a whitelisting in my view. At first glance the code seems to be working like this but didn't check yet.

Comment: Note that using HtmlAgilityPack to prevent XSS in this case is hopeless. To allow links in your html, you would need to allow an `<a>` tag with its href attribute, but then `<a href="javascript:alert(1)">` is a trivial XSS which will be allowed through and that's just one example.

Comment: Also if there is a preview on the client (user edits markdown and previews html without a server roundtrip), you will face DOM XSS if sanitization is on the server only, another reason why HtmlAgilityPack (by itself) would be inadequate to prevent XSS in this case.

Comment: As an example for what you might forget: The code might forget to touch attributes entirely, or it might miss XHTML DTD. Who knows what HTML/XML feature was not considered at all. Also Gabors example... did you think of that?!

Comment: The code is correct as far as I can tell but that's what everyone says until a vulnerability is found. You're saying it yourself: "it removes". It does not add known correct data to a clean document. It removes. That's blacklisting. And I gave you examples for what you might forget to remove. Also, did you take note of this?: `White and blacklisting are of course equivalent from a functional standpoint. The difference is that blacklisting if prone to bugs due to forgetting something.`. I am not arguing that code has a bug.

Comment: Maybe this is better: With whitelisting, anything that you forget is safe. With blacklisting anything that you forget might be a vulnerability. Before you read and validated that code, did you remember to check for XHTML features and javascript links? If not my point is proven.

Comment: Until now I was sure that *blacklisting* means when I **enumerate what are not allowed**, and *whitelisting* means when I **enumerate what are allowed**. Now I'm not sure anymore :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the code in the article. I made an important change, I removed `style` attributes from the whitelist completely. I don't need them, the styling which I allow can be achieved by classes. Also, `style` attributes are also dangerous and hard to encode/escape properly. Now I feel that the code is safe enough for my current purposes.

Comment: It looks like a `href="javascriptjavajavascriptscript:alert('')"` would lead to an unsanitized JavaScript link. The code that sanitized href URLs is awkwardly designed regardless of this vulnerability. This is why blacklisting fails: He tried to detect bad stuff and removes it. Instead, he should have checked for e.g. `^http://"` values and disallowed anything else. Also not sure what he is up to with the `eval` check. Seems to do nothing but if it does something it's probably vulnerable as well. The rest of the attribute handling seems broken as well. "class" is not CSS and he double encodes.

Comment: Thanks for the notes. I also noticed the broken class handlong and fixed it already. The other one is a good catch, thank you.

Comment: @usr What do you think about allowing `href`s beginning with `/` besides `http://` for relative paths?

Comment: I think that's equivalent to a controlled redirect from a security standpoint (e.g. `/login?returnUrl=attackerControlledValue`). This is often an attack target. For example it could be the URL `/performWireTransfer?amount=100&to=attackerAccountNumber`. In other words your site must be XSS safe. Update: The attacker can do the same thing with an http link so I think you can disregard that fear. Here's more: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet Seems like esoteric concerns to me...

Comment: Yes that's true, but I think this goes further than XSS itself. I mean one should never ever allow critical actions via GET requests for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you allow html to be edited on the client and stored to the server, you are basically opening up a can of worms. This applies to client side html editors, and also to your usecase where you want to save html generated from markdown. The problem is that a malicious user may send any html to your backend, not just one that can actually be generated from the markdown. Html code in this case will be plain user input and as such must not be trusted.

Say you want to implement whitelisting of tags and tag attributes, the HTMLAgilityPack way. Consider a simple link in html. You obviously want to allow the `<a>` tag, and also the `href` attribute to that so that links are possible. But what about `<a href="javascript:alert(1)">` then? It will be vulnerable to obvious XSS, and this is just one example, it would be vulnerable in numerous ways.

Even worse is that you probably want to render user-given html on the client before a server roundtrip (something like a preview), and also save it to your database and render it after downloading it again. For this you have to turn off request validation, and also automatic encoding as those would make this impossible.

So you have a few options that could actually work to prevent XSS.

- **Client-side sanitization**: You could use the client-side sanitizer from [Google Caja](https://developers.google.com/caja/) (only the Javascript library, not the whole thing) to remove Javascript from any html content. The way this would work is before displaying any such html (before previewing html on the client, or before displaying html downloaded from the server), you would run it through Caja, and that would remove any Javascript, thus eliminating XSS. It works reasonably well in my experience, it removes Javascript from CSS too, and also the trivial ones like href, src, a script tag, event attributes (onclick, onmouseover, etc). Another similar library is [HTML Purify](https://github.com/yahoo/html-purify), but that only works for new browsers and does not remove Javascript from CSS (because that does not work in newer browsers anyway).
- **Server-side sanitization**: You could also use Caja on the server side properly, but that's probably way too difficult and hard to maintain for your usecase, and also if only this is implemented, preview on the client (without a server roundtrip) would still be vulnerable to DOM XSS.
- **Content-Security-Policy**: You could use the `Content-Security-Policy` response header to disable all inline Javascript on your website. One drawback is that it has implications on your client-side architecture (you cannot have inline Javascript at all, obviously), and also browser support is limited, and in unsupported browsers your page will in fact be vulnerable to XSS. However, the latest version of current major browser all support Content-Security-Policy, so it is indeed a good option.
- **Separate frame**: You could serve unsafe html from a different origin (ie. a different subdomain) and accept the risk of XSS on that origin. However, cross-frame communication would still be a problem, and so would authentication and/or CSRF depending on the solution. This is kind of the old school way, options above are probably better for your usecase.

You could also use a combination of these for defense in depth.